# Show Apple emoji on Windows

Tags: html, emoji

We have sign of the horn emoji here:
https://emojipedia.org/sign-of-the-horns/

I used it on my website. My partner check it and say me - WTF dude.

I used it on MacOS and that emoji look great. Partner look it in Windows 10 and it look terribly with the black outline!

So, is it real to show Apple emoji on all devices? Ok-ok we can set it by img, but it's not clear.

Comment: Can you show us the issue? or link the website you have but the emoji on

Comment: @connorg98 Apple macOS Sierra: http://prntscr.com/k49f4b
The same button on Windows 10: http://prntscr.com/k49fht

Comment: Emojis change based on OS for example the Mac Emoji obviously will show the Apple emoji however when using windows it shows the Microsoft version of that emoji :)

Answer (score 0):

The displayed emoji depends on the installed and used fonts. So in addition to differences between OS, there might also be differences if you install  another system-font.

If you want to display the same icon everywhere using Unicode emojis, you will need to involve icon-fonts or provide a font, in which that emoji is included.

Alternatively you can include an image on that button. (Using the `button` element). Be aware though, not to use the Apple-Icon on your website, as there is most likely copyright on such icons. Create your own icon instead or use a license-free version.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography